# How to remove red border of text box after clicking on submit button

Tags: jquery

**Current code:**

```js
    /******Function checkRequired()*************/
   function checkRequired() {
       /**********In the starting of function error test are remove after entering proper input but red border still as it is*******************/
       $("#elmFirstNameError").html(" ");
       $("#elmMiddleNameError").html(" ");
       $("#elmLastNameError").html(" ");

       var firstname = $("#firstnameId").val().trim();
       var lastname = $("#lastnameId").val().trim();
       var middlename = $("#middlenameId").val().trim();
       if (firstname == "") {
         // $("#firstnameId").removeClass("errorMsg");
         $("#firstnameId").addClass("red-border");
         $("#elmFirstNameError").text("Please Enter First Name");

         return false;
       }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
    <label for="txtFirstName">First Name<span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type=text name="firstname" id="firstnameId" class="" maxlength="30">
  </td>
  <td id="elmFirstNameError" class="errorMsg">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <label for="txtMiddleName">Middle Name<span class="required"></span>
    </label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type=text name="middlename" id="middlenameId" maxlength="30">
  </td>
  <td id="elmMiddleNameError" class="errorMsg">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <label for="txtLastName">Last Name<span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type=text name="lastname" id="lastnameId" maxlength="30">
  </td>
  <td id="elmLastNameError" class="errorMsg">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you explain your question?

Comment: Your CSS is probably setting `.red-border {border: red;}` so you need to remove this class, the opposite of  `$("#firstnameId").addClass("red-border");`

Comment: @BBrown you can post your answer. I will mark it as right.

Comment: I recommend making your post more useful to others by removing some of any code that is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is probably setting

```
.red-border {
     border: red;
}
```

so you need your JavaScript event handler to remove this class. Do something that is the opposite of your line of JavaScript code that is making the element red:

```
$("#firstnameId").addClass("red-border");
```